# My viewport container is simply not responsive

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Hello I have created this viewport as my main interface for my app:

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.newDashboard',

    controller: 'newDashboard',
    reference: 'dashboard',
 
     layout: {
         type: 'border',
         align: 'stretch '
     },

    style: {
        'backgroundColor': '#909090 !important'
    },

    items: [{
         region: 'north',
         html: '',
         border: false,
         collapsible: false, ...
```

With north, west and center region panels.
What config should I apply in order to make my container responsive?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hbox or vbox layout, or a combination of the 2 (but that would imply adding an extra nested panel).

https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#layouts

Comment: You mean to add the target container as an item with the hbox config ?

Comment: If you provide a working fiddle with your code I can try and help you out

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Ext.plugin.Responsive](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.plugin.Responsive.html) plugin. You can manipulate `cfgs` based on
[responsive formulas](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.plugin.Responsive.html#cfg-responsiveFormulas) so your dashboard is more responsive.

Comment: If i want to apply responsiveness on my center region, how to do it ?

Comment: You can edit all cfgs you want (based on the mode e.g. screen width <> 800 px). For example you can change the width of your regions or collapse or hide a region that is not necessary. The only limit is that you can only edit @cfgs with the responive plugin. If you make an example I can try and help you with that (Just use the https://fiddle.sencha.com/)